# Ajax calling Area Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to call a Controller from Ajax, but I'm getting:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

The Ajax is calling from the Admin View to the Admin Controller. I can view the Admin Page, but I'm unable to call GetAll() and GetAllUsers() from Ajax or any other method.

In Startup

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {

            routes.MapRoute("areaRoute",template:"{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

In AdminController

```
namespace Project.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Area("Admin")]
    [Authorize(Policy = "AdminOnly")]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {    
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public AdminController()
        {        
        }
        [HttpGet("GetAll/{page}")]
        public IActionResult GetAll(int? page)
        {           
        }
        [HttpGet("GetAllUsers/{page}")]
        public IActionResult GetAllUsers(int? page)
        {         
        }
    }
}
```

Ajax:

```
@section Scripts{ 
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial")
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Admin/GetAll",                
                traditional: true,
                success: function (view) {
                    $("Result").html(view)
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Admin/GetAllUsers",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (view) {
                    $("userResult").html(view)
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: whats the url it is trying to access (check browser console) and see it is a valid url for a request in your system.

Comment: @Shyju The Url is https://localhost:44348/Admin/GetAllUsers

Comment: No, the URL would be localhost:44348/admin/admin/getallusers, the way you have it configured. The area name is part of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

in the url you need to user /{areaName}/{controllerName}/{ActionMethod}

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Admin/Admin/GetAllUsers",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (view) {
                $("userResult").html(view)
            }
        });
```